# iPhone: can we use Tab bar controller in view base application

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

can we use **UITab bar controller** in **view base application** thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can..
For that you have to create UITabBarViewController and its Object then refrence it with you Application..like :

in your AppDelegate.h

```
@interface youAppDelegate.h : UIApplicationDelegate {
     UIWindow *window;
     YourViewController *viewController;
     // Declare Your TabBarController Here
     UITabBarController *tabBar;
}
@property (nonautomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonautomic, retain) IBOutlet TabBarViewController *tabBar;

@end
```

in you implementation file's ApplicationDidFinish Launching add the following Code

```
viewController = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
[viewController addSubView:tabBar];
[self.window addSubView:viewController];
```

In interface builder you have to add the TabBarController to your MainWindow and relate it with the IBOutLet. Give what ever view you want to display in tabBar.

enjoy..

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

you can look at the "TheElements" example that apple provides.
you can find it here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TheElements/Introduction/Intro.html

look at the app delegate.
its very strait forward example.

for you request i tried to make a simple example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [self setupPortraitUserInterface];

    return YES;
}



- (UINavigationController *)AchievementsControllerWrappingViewController:(NSInteger*)tabIndex{

switch(tabIndex){
case 0:
    FirstViewController *theViewController;
    theViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
   break;

case 1:
    SecondViewController *theViewController;
    theViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
   break;
}

   UINavigationController *theNavigationController;
   theNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:theViewController];
    [theViewController release];

    return theNavigationController;

}



- (void)setupPortraitUserInterface {


    UINavigationController *localNavigationController;

    UIWindow *localWindow;
    localWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window = localWindow;

    [localWindow release];


    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *localViewControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){

    localNavigationController = [self AchievementsControllerWrappingViewController:i];
    [localViewControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];
    [localNavigationController release];

    }

    tabBarController.viewControllers = localViewControllersArray;
    [localViewControllersArray release];

    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];


}
```

i am not next to xCode and i did it with text edit, so please check it when you use it.

shani

Comment: Thank you shani, can you send me simple example

Comment: i have added an example to the answer. hope it will help.